# Google Apps Script Trigger 1st thursday of every month

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a trigger to run on the 1st Thursday of every month but cant seem to get this to work correctly. I know how to create the weekday trigger:

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
  .timeBased()
  .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.THURSDAY)
  .atHour(9)
  .create();
```

But I don't know how to specify that this needs to be the first Thursday of every month. I would assume I can use an IF statement and say if the date is less than 7 it should run, but that seems overly complicated. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't think that you can define the first Thursday of the month when creating the trigger.   When the function runs, which would be every Thursday, you could do some calculations, and determine if it's the first Thursday, otherwise just quit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Ben, nested time trigger in Class ClockTriggerBuilder cannot be done and is only fixed in some time trigger. Here is the link for more [details](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder). You can find other triggers for your apps Script like [snippet](http://bunkat.github.io/later/parsers.html#cron).

Comment: Thanks Mr.Rebot. I think I figured out a work around by building an array of dates in a spreadsheet and using those to determine when to run the scripts. Since I need the same trigger on ~40 spreadsheets, this made the most sense so I could have a central point of control.